# Upper bound for Explore-then-commit Bandit algorithm

Tags: probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds, concentration-of-measure

Background: From the [blog](https://banditalgs.com/2016/09/14/first-steps-explore-then-commit/),
"The explore-then-commit strategy is characterized by a natural number m, which is the number of times each arm will be explored before committing. Thus the algorithm will explore for m*K rounds before choosing a single action for the remaining n-mK rounds. We can write this strategy formally as:

\begin{align*} 
A_t = \begin{cases} 
i\,, & \text{if } (t \operatorname{mod} K)+1 = i  \text{ and } t \leq mK\,; \\ 
\text{argmax}_i \hat \mu_i(mK)\,, & t > mK\,, 
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}

where ties in the argmax will be broken in a fixed arbitrary way and $\hat \mu_i(t) $ is the average pay-off for arm i up to round t:

\begin{align*} 
\hat \mu_i(t) = \frac{1}{T_i(t)} \sum_{s=1}^t \tt 1{A_s = i} X_s\,. 
\end{align*}

Now the regret is defined as:

\begin{align*} 
R_n = m \sum_{i=1}^K \Delta_i + (n-mK) \sum_{i=1}^K \Delta_i \mathbb P{i = \text{argmax}_j \hat \mu_j(mK)}\,, 
\end{align*}

"

In the next step, they upper bound the argmax as:

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb P{i = \text{argmax}_j \hat \mu_j(mK)} 
&\leq \mathbb P{\hat \mu_i(mK) – \hat \mu_1(mK) \geq 0} \\ 
&= \mathbb P{\hat \mu_i(mK) – \mu_i – \hat \mu_1(mK) + \mu_1 \geq \Delta_i}\,. 
\end{align*}

I am unable to understand this upper bound of the argmax inside the probability. Can anyone please clarify it for me?

Comment: hi shashank, can you please check the latex edits? Also in this following part - is the part $i = \text{argmax}_j \hat \mu_j(mK)$ part of the probability? $R_n = m \sum_{i=1}^K \Delta_i + (n-mK) \sum_{i=1}^K \Delta_i \mathbb P{i = \text{argmax}_j \hat \mu_j(mK)}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rahul for your quick reply. Sorry about the messy latex edit. Thanks for editing the latex equations. Yes, the 'i= argmax' part is within the probability function.

Answer (score 2):

The question is harder to understand due to the lack of placement of brackets. Does this help?

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb P[{i = \text{argmax}_j \hat \mu_j(mK)}] &= \mathbb P[{\hat \mu_i(mK) \geq \hat \mu_1(mK)\wedge\hat \mu_i(mK) \geq \hat \mu_2(mK)\wedge
\dots\wedge\hat \mu_i(mK) \geq \hat \mu_m(mK)}] \\
&\leq \mathbb P[{\hat \mu_i(mK) \geq \hat \mu_1(mK)}]\\
&\leq \mathbb P[{\hat \mu_i(mK) – \hat \mu_1(mK) \geq 0}]\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul for your answer. Sorry, I am still not able to grasp the RHS in the first equation. It would be great if you could explain it in writing too.

Comment: From the first inequality (second line), I gather that since 'mu_1' is the maximum and if 'mu_i' > 'mu_1', then i would be choosen as 'argmax', but couldn't figure out the meaning of the RHS on line 1.

Comment: for something to be the maximum, it has to be bigger than all other. so $\mu_i$ has to be bigger than $\{\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_m\}$. Does this help?

Comment: Right. Makes sense. I was slightly confused by the notation. Sorry, for the silly question, now it seems kind of obvious. Thanks a lot for your clarification.